# Symfony2 move app.php from web directory to root directory

Tags: symfony

I moved `app.php` from web directory to root and i change the following two lines:

```php
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/app/AppKernel.php';
```

Also i move `.htaccess` file from web directory to root , my problem is that now the system cannot find JavaScript and CSS files.

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Comment: Because i am deploying my website on shared hosting , so i need when the user access my website to land to home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your composer.json you have these lines:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
```

You need to update those and run `composer update` to make your `bootstrap.php.cache` file ready for the new structure.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You need to move all content from "web" to "/".</del> see @Marcel Burkhard answer

Also you need to "play" a little with .htaccess, because allowing everyone to read your config is very bad.